# unable to install reliability package "pip install reliability"

Tags: python-3.x, reliability

We had some problem of importing reliability library from Power BI.

[image: Power BI Source]

We tried uninstalling the library 'reliability'.

and now when I try reinstalling it, facing below error.
Could someone help me resolve the issue.

```py
    C:\Users\sm55267>pip install reliablity
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/reliablity/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/reliablity/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/reliablity/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/reliablity/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))': /simple/reliablity/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/reliablity/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/reliablity/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement reliablity
ERROR: No matching distribution found for reliablity
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related with Power Bi, but with the pip command, you can try to reinstall it by:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip
```

Anyway, currently only these Python libraries are supported in Power BI:

- matplotlib
- numpy
- pandas
- scikit-learn
- scipy
- seaborn
- statsmodels

You can refer to the documentation: [Python visualizations in Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/python-visualizations-in-power-bi-service/)